# How to remove a mass action in dropdown when it is disabled in configuration?

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog, massaction, product-grid

I create a **new mass action** and I try to **remove it** when it is **disabled in configuration**

[image]

Comment: Are you using normal grid or Ui grid?

Comment: I use UI component to create a  mass action "append Text"  you find my code  below

Answer (score 0):

I use UI component to create mass action "append Text"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <!-- add mass action -->
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <action name="appendname">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">Append Text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Append Text</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="actions/append/new"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
</listingToolbar >
```